# How to extract multiple day and time from a string in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I am developing an app using Kotlin that displays the operating hours of a mini mart. I am currently trying to reformat a given string of operating time of a mini mart so that I can display it in a string based on the mini mart's daily operating hours (I am reading from an API). The strings I am given are for example,

```
val string1 = "Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
val string2 = "Mon-Sun 11:00 am - 10:30 pm" 
val string3 = "Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10:00 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 10:30 pm"
```

and I want to make them into a single string like

```
Mon 11:30 am - 9:00 pm  
Tue 11:30 am - 9:00 pm  
Wed 11:30 am - 9:00 pm 
Thu 11:30 am - 9:00 pm  
Fri 11:30 am - 9:30 pm  
Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm 
Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 pm
```

I appreciate your time to look into my problem.

Comment: Use substring :)

Comment: @gcantoni the problem is more complicated than just substring. `"Mon-Sun 11:00 am - 10:30 pm"` how would you use substring here to get you a list of 7 dates and times ?

Comment: you need to define what format you want with server side

Comment: I don't see any `9:00 pm` in your first 3 strings? Where did it come from in the second snippet?

Comment: Hi @Arpit_Shukla, it is just a format example. I will change string1 to match the output. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: @tadev, I am reading from a simple endpoint which is for education purpose, so I am given a list of strings and I cannot define the format that I want from the server side. All I can do is read it remotely and format it in my view model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function first creates a list of periods containing all possible combinations, like *Mon-Tue, Mon-Wed, Mon-Thu, ..., Fri-Sat, Fri-Sun, Sat-Sun.* The seven days are then appended to that list.

The main code works like this for this initial string:

*Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9:30 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm*

1. Split string by "/"

   Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9:30 pm
   Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm
2. For each item split by the first digit found (and trim)

   parts[0]: Mon-Thu, Sun
   parts[1]: 11:30 am - 9:30 pm
3. For each parts[0] split by comma to get the periods (and trim)

   Mon-Thu
   Sun
4. For each period filter *periods* and return the list with all days of that period

   [ Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu ]
5. Return pairs with the index of the day within the week and the output string

   1 to "Mon 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
   2 to "Tue 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
   3 to "Wed 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
   4 to "Thu 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
6. Sort the result list by the index of the day within the week
7. Return the list joined by newlines

_

```
fun convert(s: String): String {
  val days = listOf("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
  val periods = days
    .flatMap { from ->
      days
        .subList(days.indexOf(from) + 1, days.count())
        .map { till -> "$from-$till" to days.subList(days.indexOf(from), days.indexOf(till) + 1) }
    } + days.map { it to listOf(it) }
  return s
    .split("/")
    .flatMap {
      val parts = it.split("(?=\\d)".toRegex(), 2).map { s -> s.trim() }
      parts[0]
        .split(",")
        .map { period -> period.trim() }
        .flatMap { period ->
          periods
            .first { p -> p.first == period }
            .second
            .map { day -> days.indexOf(day) to "$day ${parts[1]}" }
        }
    }
    .sortedBy { it.first }
    .joinToString("\n") { it.second }
}

val string1 = "Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 9:30 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
val string2 = "Mon-Sun 11:00 am - 10:30 pm"
val string3 = "Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10:00 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 10:30 pm"
val string4 = "Wed 9:30 am - 9:30 pm / Thu 10:00 am - 7:30 pm / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 10:30 pm"
val string5 = "Fri 12:30 am - 7:30 pm"

println(convert(string1) + "\n")
println(convert(string2) + "\n")
println(convert(string3) + "\n")
println(convert(string4) + "\n")
println(convert(string5) + "\n")
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/H-RjNlz2n)